# Best practice with dynamic string/List<string> parameters

Tags: c#, class, interface

I want to pass either `string` or `List<string>` as a parameter, like the way I could do in JavaScript, and then evaluate what type is it and do the appropriate actions. Now I can do it like this:

```
public static class TestParser
{

    static void Parse(string inputFile)
    {
        // Lots of code goes in here
    }

    static void Parse(List<string> inputFileList)
    {
        // Lots of code goes in here too
    }
}
```

What the code inside these methods do, is basically Parsing with some programs either one file or list of files, depends what type is given.

If I will have lots of code, should I duplicate it, or should I create sub method which will contain the code, or is there another cool way I can do this in c#?

Comment: You should extract common code into separate, `private` method(s) and call it/them from `Parse`. Code duplication is never a good thing.

Comment: We don't have enough context. What is this method doing? Can you delegate from one method to the other in some way?

Comment: if the base functionality is the same in the string method as the List method, and all the difference is that you loop/iterate in the List method, then I would just put the base functionality in the String method and have the List method call the string method. That way it's all in one place and your overload is just handling the extra parsing things you want to do.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the params keyword

Comment: @skmasq: I realized based on Servy's comment that the extra helper method is actually not needed.  Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on exactly what Parse() is supposed to do, a reasonable pattern might be

```
static void Parse(string inputFile)
{
    // Lots of code goes in here
}

static void Parse(List<string> inputFileList)
{
    foreach (var inputFile in inputFileList)
        Parse(inputFile);
}
```

**UPDATE**

The alternative has been suggested to create a `new List<string>() { inputFile}` and call `Parse(List<string>)` instead of separating the processing code out into a separate method.

```
static void Parse(List<string> inputFileList)
{
    // Lots of code goes in here too
}

static void Parse(string inputFile)
{
    Parse(new List<string>() { inputFile });
}
```

In almost all cases, this is only a question of style.  I prefer my solution because it is clearer at first glance (to me, at least) what is happening, and because I have worked on very high volume systems where the CLR's ability to dispose short-lived objects became a performance issue.  99.99% of even performance critical apps will not run into that particular issue.

Any performance difference will only manifest if you have such a high volume of separate calls that you are pushing the CLR's CG to the breaking point. If you have a modest to even high volume of calls to the method, `// Lots of code goes in here`'s processing time is likely to make the performance cost of creating the new list nearly immeasurable.

For nearly all cases, the two approaches differ only in style, and are both appropriate.

Comment: +1. I was 7 seconds too late :). Consider changing names of parameters to lowerCase despite OP's style.

Comment: Why would you have three functions and not just call `Parse(string)` from `Parse(List<string>)`?

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Even though there are few cases where it would matter in real life, I'm not a fan of creating additional objects that are not necessary.  I have worked on very high volume systems where that actually mattered.

Comment: @EricJ. That wouldn't involve the creation of any additional objects.

Comment: Now I am a bit confused, was is the difference between these two answers, keeping in mind that for this particular case `Performance` is priority.

Comment: @skmasq you can use either- IMO this one is more structured for readability (at first glance it is more clear what is happening, and you can private all your `//lots of code here` section)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yes, that hurt my eyes as soon as I saw it :-)

Comment: @EricJ. You can simply switch which overload of `Parse` you put the actual implementation in to avoid the creation of a sequence object, in the event that you're actually concerned about it.  And that's the exact suggestion you were given to begin with; you were the only one thinking about providing the implementation in the method that would require you to create an unneeded sequence object.

Comment: @Servy: Alexei's deleted answer is the one I replicate in the update.  You're right of course about the helper method being unnecessary (pre-coffee answer :-)  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

write your parse method as you would

then call it from the looping method

```
public static class TestParser
{

    static void Parse(string InputFile)
    {
        // Lots of code goes in here
    }

    static void Parse(List<string> InputFileList)
    {
        foreach(string path in InputFileList)
        {
            Parse(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>`, internally, isn't a list (in the CS sense). It's an array that gets reallocated as necessary. Assuming that the core parsing logic is identical regardless of whether the method is passed 1, 2 or more strings, I would do something like this, implementing the logic to handle a single item:

```
static void Parse( string s )
{
  // core logic for processing an individual item
}
```

Then add suitable overloads. I would first add the generic version:

```
static void Parse( params string[] list )
{
  Parse( (IEnumerable<string> list ) ;
}

static void Parse( IEnumerable<T> list )
{
  foreach( string s in list )
  {
    Parse(s) ;
  }
  return ;
}
```

The first version above (`params string[]`) lets you invoke the method with variable numbers of arguments:

```
Parse( "foo" , "bar" ) ;
Parse( "foo" , "bar" , "baz" , "bat" ) ;
```

The second version above (`IEnumerable<T>`) accepts anything that implements `IEnumerable<T>`: pretty much any standard collection, so it will accept things like:

```
List<string> listOfStrings = PopulateList() ;
Parse( listOfStrings ) ;

string[] arrayOfStrings = listOfStrings().ToArray() ;
Parse( arrayOfStrings ) ;
```

Not to mention things like `HashSet<string>`, `TreeSet<string>`, etc.

You can even use LINQ's deferred execution with this overload:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadStringsFromFile( string fileName )
{
  using ( StreamReader reader = File.OpenText( fn ) )
  {
    string s ;
    while ( null != (s=reader.ReadLine()) )
    {
      yield return s ;
    }
  }
}

...

Parse( ReadStringsFromFile() ) ;
```

which will chain the methods together: the file will be read a line at a time and each line processed individually.

You could also write an *extension method* to let you chain the method calls together:

```
public static void ParseEach( this IEnumerable<T> string strings )
{
  foreach ( string s in strings )
  {
     Parse(s) ;
  }
}
```

which lets you say something like

```
ReadStringsFromFile().ParseEach() ;
```